# Sendkeys in webdriver appending text twice for android mobile app, How to solve?

Tags: java, android, webdriver, appium, sendkeys

```
un.click();
    un.clear();
    un.sendKeys("600165");
```

When I send value to username field in mobile app, sendkeys appending twice.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Why do you click it first?

Comment: Perhaps it contains a default value that needs to be cleared? If it doesn't, those first two steps are unnecessary, but that wouldn't explain this behavior. Can you provide an inspector view of your application?